# What is the limit of columns that PDFMAKE accepts?

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I am busy with this library to print a table with dynamic data that I put together with angular, the problem that occurs when there are too many columns, the library does not cover all the information of the table, I am trying to use the 'auto' but there is still no information missing to show, also lowering the source but still not capable.

I don't know if it is necessary to build the table to print in another way or if it is simply not possible to show so many columns

[image: TablePDF]

```js
/**
 * Servicio para la generaci\u00F3n de documento PDF
 */
printPagePDF() {
  this.generateDocDefinition();
  const ventana = window.open('', '_blank');
  pdfMake.createPdf(this.docDefinicion).print({}, ventana);
}

/**
 * Procesa la informaci\u00F3n de la grilla y la traduce en una estructura compatible para la generaci\u00F3n de un archivo en formato PDF.
 */
generateDocDefinition() {
  let pdfTitulo = '';
  const pdfEncabezado = [];
  let pdfFila = [];
  const pdfFilas = [];
  let pdfTabla;
  const pdfDatos = [];
  const anchoColumna = [];
  this.titulosGrid = this.titulosGrilla;
  this.columnasGrid = this.evalDataExport();
  this.datosGrid = this.listadoResultado;
  // Armado de Titulo Reporte
  for (let i = 0; this.titulosGrid.length > i; i++) {
    pdfEncabezado.push({
      // T\u00EDtulo de la hoja de la planilla. Pueden ser "N" captions.
      text: this.titulosGrid[i] + ' ', // String con el t\u00EDtulo del caption.
      style: 'pdfTitle', // Tipo de dato del caption.
      alignment: 'center', // Alineaci\u00F3n del t\u00EDtulo en la celda.
    });
    pdfTitulo += this.titulosGrid[i] + '\r\n';
  }
  // Agregar Titulo a Arreglo de Tabla
  pdfFila.push({
    text: pdfTitulo,
    bold: true,
    colSpan: this.columnasGrid.length,
    style: 'tableHeader',
  });
  for (let i = 1; i < this.columnasGrid.length; i++) {
    pdfFila.push({});
  }
  pdfFilas.push(pdfFila);
  pdfFila = [];
  // Calcula Anchos
  for (let i = 0; i < this.columnasGrid.length; i++) {
    anchoColumna.push('*');
  }
  pdfDatos.push({
    text: pdfEncabezado,
    style: 'pdfTitle',
  });
  // Generar Headers de Columnas
  for (let h = 0; h < this.columnasGrid.length; h++) {
    pdfFila.push({
      text: this.columnasGrid[h].header,
      style: 'tableHeader',
      alignment: 'center',
      field: this.columnasGrid[h].field,
    });
  }
  pdfFilas.push(pdfFila);
  pdfFila = [];
  // Generar Arreglo de Tabla
  // Iterar cada registro de la grilla
  for (let fila = 0; fila < this.datosGrid.length; fila++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < this.columnasGrid.length; col++) {
      const id = this.columnasGrid[col].field;
      /// Todo lo que no sea n\u00FAmero asignar el tipo de datos string
      if (isNaN(this.datosGrid[fila][id]) || this.datosGrid[fila][id] === null || this.datosGrid[fila][id] === '') {
        let texto;
        if (this.datosGrid[fila][id] === undefined || this.datosGrid[fila][id] === null) {
          texto = '';
        } else {
          texto = this.datosGrid[fila][id];
        }
        pdfFila.push({
          text: texto,
          style: 'tableData',
          alignment: 'left',
        });
      } else {
        if (id === 'fecha' || id === 'fecHas') {
          const fecha = new Date(this.datosGrid[fila][id]);
          let formatoFecha;
          if (this.parametros['tipoSerie'] == appConstants.shfhSeriesDiaria) {
            formatoFecha =
              fecha.getDate().toLocaleString('es-CH', {
                minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
                useGrouping: false,
              }) +
              '/' +
              (fecha.getMonth() + 1).toLocaleString('es-CH', {
                minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
                useGrouping: false,
              }) +
              '/' +
              fecha.getFullYear();
          }
          if (this.parametros['tipoSerie'] == appConstants.shfhSerieSemanal) {
            formatoFecha =
              fecha.getDate().toLocaleString('es-CH', {
                minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
                useGrouping: false,
              }) +
              '/' +
              (fecha.getMonth() + 1).toLocaleString('es-CH', {
                minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
                useGrouping: false,
              }) +
              '/' +
              fecha.getFullYear();
          }
          if (this.parametros['tipoSerie'] == appConstants.shfhSerieMensual) {
            formatoFecha =
              (fecha.getMonth() + 1).toLocaleString('es-CH', {
                minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
                useGrouping: false,
              }) +
              '/' +
              fecha.getFullYear();
          }
          pdfFila.push({
            text: formatoFecha,
            style: 'tableData',
            alignment: 'right',
          });
        } else {
          const numero = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CH').format(this.roundDecimals(this.datosGrid[fila][id], 2));
          pdfFila.push({
            text: numero,
            style: 'tableData',
            alignment: 'right',
          });
        }
      }
    }
    pdfFilas.push(pdfFila);
    pdfFila = [];
  }
  // Agregar footers
  pdfFila.push({
    text: [
      'Fuente: ',
      {
        text: 'ODEPA',
        link: 'https://www.odepa.gob.cl/',
      },
      '.',
    ],
    colSpan: this.columnasGrid.length,
    style: 'tableHeader',
    alignment: 'left',
  });
  pdfFilas.push(pdfFila);
  pdfFila = [];
  pdfTabla = {
    table: {
      headerRows: 2, // dontBreakRows: true,
      // keepWithHeaderRows: 1,
      widths: anchoColumna,
      body: pdfFilas,
    },
    margin: [0, 5, 0, 15],
  };
  pdfDatos.push(pdfTabla);
  // Definicion de Datos PDF
  this.docDefinicion = {
    info: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(appConstants.PDF_INFO).replace('[title]', 'Series hist\u00F3ricas de precios diarios internacionales de productos basicos').replace('[keywords]', 'Series hist\u00F3ricas de precios diarios internacionales de productos basicos')),
    pageSize: appConstants.PDF_PAGINA_TAMANIO,
    pageOrientation: appConstants.PDF_PAGINA_ORIENTACION_L,
    pageMargins: appConstants.PDF_PAGINA_MARGEN,
    footer: {
      columns: [{
          text: 'ODEPA - Oficina de Estudios y Pol\u00EDticas Agrarias.',
          alignment: 'left',
          style: 'tableData',
          margin: [20, 0],
        },
        {
          text: 'Documento generado el ' + new Date().toLocaleString(),
          alignment: 'right',
          style: 'tableData',
          margin: [20, 0],
        },
      ],
    },
    content: pdfDatos,
    styles: appConstants.PDF_ESTILO,
  };
}
```

Here I attach all the method that I am doing to print the table with that library.

And as you can see in the attached photo, the information I need to print does not come out completely, be careful even if I attach the sheet horizontally.

I am thinking that simply when there is too much information the user cannot print the document

Comment: It worked for me with `pagesize: 'TABLOID'`  and leaving the width in 'auto'